# Azure Devops Docker Compose Build

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

Does Azure [Docker-Compose V0](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/blob/80093b83bae8e8833b88e9384e283a20672914f4/Tasks/DockerComposeV0/dockercomposebuild.ts) Task support building individual service instead of building all the services?

Below is the yaml dump of docker compose task. I want to build the individual service from the environment variable. But this always builds all the images.

```
steps:
- task: DockerCompose@0
  displayName: 'Run a Docker Compose command'
  inputs:
    containerregistrytype: 'Container Registry'
    dockerComposeFile: 'pathto/docker-compose.yml'
    dockerComposeCommand: build
    arguments: '$(ProjectName)'
```

Build output with debug flag=true

```
[debug]arguments:
[debug]   -f
[debug]   /pathToCompose/docker-compose.yml
[debug]   -f
[debug]   /myagent/.docker-compose.1583974576607.yml
[debug]   -p
[debug]   repository
[debug]   build
/usr/sbin/docker-compose -f /pathToCompose/docker-compose.yml -f /myagent/.docker-compose.1583974576607.yml -p repository build
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does Azure Docker-Compose V0 Task support building individual service
>   instead of building all the services?

Yes, it does.

Just specify the `service name` you want to build in `argument` of task, which is what you were trying.

You need set system.debug to true in variables tab, then confirm your detailed log to confirm whether `$(ProjectName)` value was passed **successfully**. Because in debug log, we print the complete command:

[image]

*`newsfeed` is one of my service name.*

---

**Update on 3/13/2020:**

The `Arguments` blank of task definition is work for `Build service images` action, which means you can input your actual arguments there only after the `Build service images` action selected:

[image]

The `Arguments` blank **does not work** along with `Run a Docker Compose command` action.

When you choose that action, the method of argument applied should look like this:

[image]

Only this, the argument can be available for task.

[image]

Comment: From the log I dont see the service being passed as argument in my case.

Even if I hard code the service name its not passed to docker-compose per log. (attached compose log with path updated)

Comment: Also one thing I see different between my log and above is I got -p repository build instead of -p Docker build 
not sure why this is different. I am using the Devops web interface for configuration not sure if thats causing any difference.

Comment: @user3279954. It's okay, Docker just my repository name:-) . From the log part you shared, it represent our system does not detect out your argument value(seems). For sure, did you check another line? I point here: https://imgur.com/a/hczt8ne What's the value of yours?

Comment: Ah okie I see.  argument doesnt seem to be passed on to docker-compose, cross checked with the logs tried `--parallel`,  Individual service name hardcoded or from  environment variable. Is there any way to identify why arguments are not passed on ?

https://imgur.com/a/4QS4bAE (config while  --parallel arg)

Comment: @user3279954, that `Arguments` blank is work for `Build service images` action, not for 
 `Run a Docker Compose command` action. If you want to apply arguments with `Run a Docker Compose command` action, you should configure it like this: https://imgur.com/a/BkmKVFr. Updated more details into answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot Merlin, passing the arguments as part of command worked.

Although the tip can be updated i guess, its misleading https://imgur.com/a/9KMgZWx